# making two fields mutually exclusive with knockout

Tags: javascript, knockout.js

I am trying to make a text input and a checkbox mutually exclusive.

By default, the textbox should contain "0" and the checkbox should be false. If the user checks the checkbox, the textbox should be blanked out. If the user enters a value in the textbox, the checkbox should be unchecked. At no time should either field become disabled or otherwise uneditable.

I have almost all of the behavior working despite one small knockout related quip. If a user types in a number into the textbox then clicks the checkbox while still focused on the textbox, the textbox value will not clear.

I believe this is happening because of the timing of the subscriptions firing, but I am not sure how to solve it.

Markup:

```
<div id="container">
    <label>Number: </label><input type="text" data-bind="value: number" /> OR
    <input type="checkbox" id="all" data-bind="checked: all" /><label  or="all">All</label>
</div>
```

Script:

```
var ViewModel = function () {
    var self = this;

    self.number = ko.observable(5);
    self.all = ko.observable(false);

    var updatedFromUser = true;

    self.number.subscribe(function (updatedNumber) {
        if (!updatedFromUser) {
            updatedFromUser = true;
            return;
        }

        updatedFromUser = false;
        self.all(updatedNumber === '');
    });

    self.all.subscribe(function (checked) {
        if (!updatedFromUser) {
            updatedFromUser = true;
            return;
        }

        updatedFromUser = false;
        if (checked) {
            self.number('');
        } else {
            self.number(0);
        }
    });
};
```

http://jsfiddle.net/rpnmvw1u/1/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By default the [`value` binding](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/value-binding.html) updates the underlying observable on the `change` event which usually happen when you leave the textbox, that is why your code is not working when clicking on the checkbox while still focused on the textbox.

You can change this behavior with the `valueUpdate` option: setting it to `afterkeydown` will update your observable as the user types in something to the textbox:

```
<input type="text" data-bind="value: number, valueUpdate: 'afterkeydown'" />
```

However in itself it won't fix your code because your current `updatedFromUser` usage is not always working correctly.

I would use a writable computed for the `all` property:

```
self.number = ko.observable(5);
self.all = ko.computed({
    read: function () {
        return self.number() === '';
    },
    write: function (checked) {
        if (checked) {
            self.number('');
        } else {
            self.number(0);
        }
    }
});
```

Demo [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/q6130om7/).

In this case KO will handle the subscriptions for you and there is no dependency circle because only `all` depends on `number`.

Comment: The fiddle does not work. Removing the `updatedFromUser` breaks the ability to type in the input box, and the original issue (clicking the checkbox while focus is in the textbox) is also not fixed.

Comment: put your cursor into the textbox, press backspace, then type 5. It changes it to 0 on you.

Comment: I see now what was not working, still I was not able to figure out what is exactly broken with your code because it should work with the `valueUpdate: 'afterkeydown'` addition... however I've come up with an alternative solution and updated my answer with it.

Comment: the combination of the writable computed and the valueUpdate is working nicely. Thank you.